# Flutter - How to display webview inside application?

Tags: android, flutter, webview

So i just starting to learn flutter and using its webview widget, but every time I open the route containing webview widget. Android always prompt me with ***open with webview browser tester*** instead of just displaying it inside my widget?

[image: Screenshot of my app]

Here is my code.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class DetailLaporanR extends StatelessWidget {
  Completer <WebViewController> _c = Completer<WebViewController>();
  final globalScaff = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: globalScaff,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Detail Laporan"),
      ),
      body: new WebView(
          initialUrl: "https://google.com",
          javaScriptMode: JavaScriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
            _c.complete(webViewController);
          },
        ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // verify and submit
              final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Generating, Please Wait...'));
              // Find the Scaffold in the widget tree and use it to show a SnackBar.
              globalScaff.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.cloud_download),
            backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs on this package:

The plugin relies on Flutter's new mechanism for embedding Android and iOS views. As that mechanism is currently in a developers preview, this plugin should also be considered a developers preview.

https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/

So it's not recommended to use in production as the api may change and relies on a feature in flutter which is not yet released in the stable versions.

Comment: is it any other alternative to display html code on my widget's body then?

Comment: I believe this is the only package that can get this feature working, might want to review this blog post from the flutter team to see if you missed something in your code: https://medium.com/flutter/the-power-of-webviews-in-flutter-a56234b57df2

Comment: i already follow this tutorial.
or maybe is there any configuration on android to enable/disable this feature?